# What is the behavior of java.util.concurrent.Future in terms of Timeout?

Tags: java

I'd like to clarify this code:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
Callable < Map < String, ? >> task = new Callable < Map < String, ? >> () {
    @Override
    public Map < String, ? > call() throws Exception {
        Map < String, ? > result = cc.execute();
        while (true) {} // notice this
        return result;
    }
};
Future < Map < String, ? >> futureResult = executor.submit(task);
Map < String, ? > result = futureResult.get(timeoutInSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Inside the task is a `while(true)` code and this task is terminated exactly the time set here `Map < String, ? > result = futureResult.get(timeoutInSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS);` as per my observation.

As there is a conversation here: https://github.com/nginx/unit/issues/278 that the `get` is not really the one that interrupts.

My question is, **what is the behavior of java.util.concurrent.Future in terms of Timeout?**

Comment: The goal of the code is to terminate inside the `task` within the time set, for example 10 seconds max.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-

Comment: The `get()` method returns the result if available within the timeout period, otherwise it throws an exception. There is nothing in the specification that says the actual task gets interrupted.

Comment: `The goal of the code is to terminate inside the task within the time set` - Your current code in the task is not responsive to interruption, so there is no possibility that you will be able to close your task gracefully.